# Problema ao consultar DB por um botão tkinter

Tags: python, query, sqlite, tkinter

Fiz uma tela que consulta apenas as linhas da tabela de um banco que dados (sqlite), que tiverem a tag 'pendencia' = 1. Se existirem 4 pendencias, 4 botões aparecem (segue a imagem [1]. Essa contrução dos botões foi feita pelo laço for abaixo.

O botão chama a função 'abrir', estou com problema de identificar qual botão foi aberto, para atualizar o campo 'status' (ultima linha do código abaixo) para 'open'.

Já tentei utilizar o 'i' como contador pra função 'abrir()', mas não da certo porque ao abrir a tela, todos os botões já foram criados, logo o 'i' sempre será o maior possível...

```
         for i in range(valor):
            b = Button(self, text=f"{i+1}ª Solicitação", font='Trebuchet 9 bold', border=5, background='#e3a27f', command=lambda:[abrir(i), self.which_button("oi")])
            b.place(x=x, y=y, width=100, height=40)
            if i<=3:
                x+=160
                y=100
            if i==3:
                x = 20
                y = 180
            if i>3:
                x += 160
                y = 180
            if i>8:
                x = 9999
                y = 9999

            def abrir(i):
                valor = pend()
                ocs = [()]
                cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM form_173 WHERE pendencia=1")
                ids = cursor.fetchall()
                for id_ in ids:
                    cursor.execute(f"SELECT oc FROM ocs WHERE track_form173 = '{id_[0]}'")
                    oc_ = cursor.fetchall()
                    ocs.append((id_[0], ocs))
                cursor.execute(f"UPDATE form_173 SET status='open' WHERE Id_form_173 = '{id_[0]}'")'''


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBSXZ.png
```

Answer (score -1):

O problema foi solucionado por esse post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments

Por lambda i=i: funcion()